# Centos 6.2 crashes (Network failure) when I restart network service

Tags: networking, centos

I connect remotely using ssh (putty). 90% of the time I tried to run a network related command, the server restarts. It becomes unavailable for few minutes and then back again. I noticed the first problem when I tried to svn checkout. I tried to restart the network service, but putty keeps giving me "Network error: Software caused connection abort". Is this a network interruption or the server shuts down and restart. it takes about 3mins for the connection to be up again.

Any idea what is going on?

here is the /var/log/messages

`Jan 26 01:04:43 appserver yum[8865]: Installed: mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-2.el6_1.4.x86_64

Jan 26 13:40:03 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  (eth1): device state change: 8 -> 3 (reason 39)

Jan 26 13:40:03 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  (eth1): deactivating device (reason: 39).

Jan 26 13:40:03 appserver avahi-daemon[1669]: Withdrawing address record for 134.245.322.12 on eth1.

Jan 26 13:40:03 appserver avahi-daemon[1669]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address 134.245.322.12.

Jan 26 13:40:03 appserver avahi-daemon[1669]: Interface eth1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.

Jan 26 13:40:03 appserver kernel: lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) starting connection 'System eth1'

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  (eth1): device state change: 3 -> 4 (reason 0)

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  (eth1): device state change: 4 -> 5 (reason 0)
Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  (eth1): device state change: 5 -> 7 (reason 0)

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) scheduled...

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) started...

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) scheduled...

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) complete.

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) started...

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver avahi-daemon[1669]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address 134.245.322.12.

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver avahi-daemon[1669]: New relevant interface eth1.IPv4 for mDNS.

Jan 26 13:40:04 appserver avahi-daemon[1669]: Registering new address record for 134.245.322.12 on eth1.IPv4.

Jan 26 13:40:05 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  (eth1): device state change: 7 -> 8 (reason 0)

Jan 26 13:40:05 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Policy set 'System eth1' (eth1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.

Jan 26 13:40:05 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) successful, device activated.

Jan 26 13:40:05 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) complete.

Jan 26 13:47:03 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  (eth1): device state change: 8 -> 3 (reason 39)

Jan 26 13:47:03 appserver NetworkManager[1655]:  (eth1): deactivating device (reason: 39).

Jan 26 13:47:03 appserver avahi-daemon[1669]: Withdrawing address record for 134.245.322.12 on eth1.

Jan 26 13:47:03 appserver avahi-daemon[1669]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address 134.245.322.12.

Jan 26 13:47:03 appserver avahi-daemon[1669]: Interface eth1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.

Jan 26 13:47:04 appserver kernel: lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions`

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in /var/log/messages ?

Comment: Just because you are being disconnected from SSH doesn't mean the server restarted, it could just be that your network connection is being interrupted.  You need to update the question with actual facts and logs if you want help in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I just attached the log message. maybe it didn't restart. But each time I am disconnected, I also try to reach the server from a traditional browser and it gives connection error as well. what other logs can I check to know the problem?

Comment: If the server network connection restart, the processes will lose their bind on the network interface. Thoses process should also be restarted afterward. Using 'w' should tell you if server restarted (uptime command also work).

Also , make sure you are using static IPs.

Comment: Why are you restarting the network services?